# Is it possible to change the swipe unlock screen on the Galaxy S series?

Tags: lock-screens

Is there any way to change the default swipe unlock screen on a galaxy S phone? I find that unlocking the screen usually requires a few attempts and is difficult for me to do with just one hand (heh, ironically the screen is too large to swipe across). I'm currently using a Captivate.

Comment: I am interested too in the answer.... i want the swipe of that galaxy 5... Is it possible... ?

Comment: my samsung mesmerize doesnt have "change screen lock"  Why might this be?  I really want the puzzle unlock to be my standard unlock

Comment: Help i tried what matthew reed said to do but i sont seem to have a change screen lock option. Bought phone (galaxy s) 2 weeksago off craigslist. It doesnt seem to have many options unlike my friend who has the same exact phone (his has a bunch load of options)

Comment: If I install WidgetLocker, then will I still have the Puzzle Piece lock screen for text and calls?  I really like that part, I just don't like the default unlock swipe.

Comment: Unfortunatly no, you will lose those features.

Comment: What version of Android are you running?  I believe 2.2.1 has about 5 different options.  All involve some swipe, but I think some require a smaller swipe than others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WidgetLocker (on the market) provides HTC-like, iPhone-like, Motorola-like, and Rotary style unlock screens.  Really superb app.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to install an app for this.  `Settings -> Location and security -> Change screen lock`.  There are 3 other options. I use **Pattern** because it's cool and easy for one hand, and relatively secure.  The **Puzzle** lock the easiest though.

Comment: the`Pattern` option is , on my Galaxy S phone, situated under the `Screen unlock settings` - meaning, I think, that this has nothing to do with the swype action of the lock screen (the other options suggest that: `None`, `PIN` and `Password`. Or am I wrong ? Or is the `none` option the normal screen with the green and red button ?

Comment: I can't really speak to what your phone does if it's different, but don't have to swipe anything while I'm using the pattern lock.

Answer (score 3):

Search on the market, there are unlock screens that forces you to do random math puzzle, play a ball game, and there is an app aptly named "No Lock" that simply disables the lock screen, and requiring you to press the hardware lock button to unlock.

Comment: Well, the goal was to be able to get access to the phone faster so the no lock was the most help. I still think HTC's down swipe unlock is best though. Any idea if there is anything similar to that on the market?